# Does the shoretel database track who has silently monitored calls?

Tags: shoretel

Is it possible to track in the shoretel database who has silently monitored others calls? If so where is the data stored? tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic sample query that will get you a list of calls that were silent monitor calls. There is obviously a lot of refining to do based on exactly what details you are looking for. Feel free to PM me if you want help with something more specific.

```
SELECT `call`.SIPCallId AS `GUID`
    , `call`.StartTime AS `StartTime`
    , `call`.Extension AS `DN`
    , `call`.DialedNumber
    FROM `call`
    LEFT JOIN connect ON (`call`.ID = connect.CallTableID)
    WHERE connect.connectreason = 21
    ORDER BY `call`.Extension, `call`.StartTime
```

The where clause here limits your rows to only those with a reason code of 21, silent monitor. Look at the values in the connectreason table for more details on what reason codes are tracked.

***PLEASE NOTE*** that this is in the CDR Database (port 4309, username of 'st_cdrreport' and readonly password of 'passwordcdrreport') *you don't want to accidentally write to the CDR database...*